# Which Life cycle method should be preferred when using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Which life cycles method should be preferred while getting data from redux store in props?

Comment: You can use componentdidmount and display a loader on the section where data to be displayed.

Comment: can you explain your use case, it depends on whats your use case, since you can block the lifecycle by using shouldComponentUpdate  to avoid re render but checking deeply nested objects or data structures gives poor performance. componentWillRecieveProps will be going to be deprecated in React 17 still it work with unsafe prefix. And if you want check then you can use getDerivedStateFromProps . It all depends on the use case

If you are asking for initial loading data for getting some response you can call it in componentDidMount

Comment: You don't need to add any lifecycle method to get the data from redux store. your component should subscribe to redux store using `react-redux` package and the component will get the updated state whenever there is any change in state.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how exactly is your component written, but the general pattern to follow would be to connect your component to your redux store, and map the value from your store to your components props.

From there, your component will be subscribed to the data from your store, which you can access on `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, and any other updates to the store can be accessed in the `componentDidUpdate` hook. Similarly, any changes on your props will trigger re-rendering on your component.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

class Checkbox extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = this.props;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState,) {

  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Checkbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will not need any life cycle method but it depends on your usecase and how you want to use your data that is coming from redux store.Generally flow can be like this:

1. Connect your component with redux store.
2. Map your state to props and get the that you want in component.
3. In componentDidMount(),you will get the data in props.
4. And if you want to check if your data is changed or not from store then you can use componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) method to check.

Here is a little demo:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("You will get your data here:",this.props.data);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState,) {
    //Here you can compare data if it is changed or not.
    if(prevProps.data !== this.props.data){
        console.log("Your data is changed.");   
    }
  }

}

//Map your state to props
const mapStateToProps = store =>{
    const data = store.data
    return {
        data
    }
};

//Connect your component with redux store.
export default connect(mapStoreToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: So componentDIdUpdate and componentDidMount Are the lifecycle methods which should be used often while using redux for props?

Comment: Yes and again it totally depends on your usecase. If you are connecting your component with store,your component will get data in props and you want to check conditions after data is updated you can use componentDIdUpdate for sure.